# jQuery Mobile - "in-page" dialog popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

I am looking for a somewhat slick solution to have an "in-page" dialog box on one of my JQM pages.  I am trying to avoid leaving the page, because the dialog popup is a "lookup" that helps a user populate a form field. I don't want to leave the actual page, so to not lose any other information the user has already entered.

My first attempt was using the simpledialog2 plugin, which I use on other parts of the site for popup menus.  While it works great for basic links, it gets really clunky on longer lists.  It feels very limited when it comes to sizing and especially scrolling.

I somewhat like the built-in JQM implementation of the dialog popup for long multiselects.  To give you an idea, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWyGZ/)

Does anyone know how this dialog popup is implemented and if I can call the same method in some way?  If not, does anyone know of alternatives to pro due such an "in-page" dialog?

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I can't use the multi-page template in JQM, because the site is built as a web app and I am relying on the AJAX loading of individual pages, which the multi-page template doesn't support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dialog you illustrated in your jsfiddle can easily be called in its own page. You can either put data-rel="dialog" in an anchor tag `<a href="dialog.html">dialog</a>`or you can add `data-role="dialog"` to your page container. Here is an example

dialog.html

```
<div data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>        
    </div>
</div>​
```

Also note that they are planning on producing the in page dialogs I believe your looking for in JQM v 1.2 . Here is a preview of that http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html. So I guess if your really patient you'll get exactly what your looking for.

Comment: I know I can call the dialog as a new page, but that would leave the current page, which I want to avoid (as all the data entered in the form would be lost).  However, the second part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't have a lot of time to wait, but I might just implement a temporary solution and wait for the release of JQM 1.2.  Thanks so much for the info.

Comment: You could keep the previous page in the dom by adding data-dom-cache="true" to the page container. That way you could still use javascript to update your form.

Comment: I don't understand why the dialog doesn't work like a popup, it's so much easier because you don't have to change page.(and lose all the users form data)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need an **undismissible** popup rather than a dialog.

```
<div data-dismissible="false" data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
  <span>Content...</span>
</div>
```

Now in javascript call,

```
$('#myPopup').popup().popup('open');
```